# Print unicode character

Tags: bash, printf

With Bash, you can use `printf` with hex codes

```
\xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
\uHHHH Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character with hex value HHHH (4 digits)
```

example

```
$ printf '\x26'
&
```

However the Unicode example does not print as expected

```
$ printf '\u0026'
\u0026
```

My Bash version

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.10(4)-release
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of `bash` are you using (`echo $BASH_VERSION` or `bash --version`)? The Unicode escapes work in `bash` 4.2, but not 3.2.48. I suspect support was added in `bash` 4.0.

Update: I can confirm it does not work in `bash` 4.1.2. This functionality appears to have been added in `bash` 4.2.

Update 2: From the [release notes for bash 4.2](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS):

> d.  `$'...'`, `echo`, and `printf` understand `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` escape 
>   sequences.

Comment: In older versions is it ok to use **$printf "%s" "%"** to print the **%** symbol ?

Comment: I assume that would be fine, as well as `printf "%%"`.