# bash-replacing a number with unicode character using sed

Tags: bash, unicode, sed, printf

So I have this output generated from printf

```
    011010
```

Now I want to pipe it and use sed to replace 0's and 1's with unicode character, so I get unicode characters printed instead of binary (011010).

I can do this just copy-pasting the characters themselves, but I want to use values instead like the ones found in unicode table:

```
    Position: 0x2701
    Decimal: 9985
    Symbol: ✁
```

How do I use the above values with sed to generate the character?

Comment: `sed` doesn't understand Unicode characters, it understands bytes, so you can't sub in U+2701. You can sub in the UTF-8 encoding of U+2701, but as far as `sed` is concerned, that's just the three bytes `\xE2`, `\x9c`, and `\x81`. (And of course that won't actually be the character U+2701 unless your output is interpreted as UTF-8.)

Comment: I tried the above but it doesn't work for some reason. if it's        sed s/1/\xE2\x9c\x81/g it doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With bash (since v4.2) or zsh, the simple solution is to use the `$'...'` syntax, which understands C escapes including `\u` escapes:

```
$ echo 011010 | sed $'s/1/\u2701/g'
0✁✁0✁0
```

If you have Gnu sed, you can use escape sequences in the `s//` command. Gnu `sed`, unfortunately, does not understand `\u` unicode escapes, but it does understand `\x` hex escapes. However, to get it to decode them, you need to make sure that it sees the backslashes. Then you can do the translation in UTF-8, assuming you know the UTF-8 sequence corresponding to the Unicode codepoint:

```
$ # Quote the argument
$ echo 011010 | sed 's/1/\xE2\x9C\x81/g'
0✁✁0✁0
$ # Or escape the backslashes
$ echo 011010 | sed s/1/\\xE2\\x9C\\x81/g
0✁✁0✁0
$ # This doesn't work because the \ is removed by bash before sed sees it
$ echo 011010 | sed s/1/\xE2\x9C\x81/g
0xE2x9Cx81xE2x9Cx810xE2x9Cx810
$ # So that was the same as: sed s/1/xE2x9Cx81/g
```

Comment: There are different `sed` dialects; not all of them understand `\xAF` escapes either.  A portable alternative might be `perl -pCSD -e 's/1/\x{2701}/g'`.

Comment: @tripleee: That's true. The bash $'...' solution is certainly superior.

Comment: This is the answer. It even worked with printf. Thank you very much @rici

Comment: Using `bash` (which is guaranteed to do C escapes) instead of `sed` (which only has them as a GNU extension) is a great idea.

Comment: @abarnert: I agree. I only mentioned the `sed` thing because of your comment to the question and the OP's reply.

Comment: @rici: Yeah, I was just explaining why your answer is great. :) But I just thought of something. Weren't `\u` escapes added to bash only in 4.0 or so, which at least some *nixes (in particular, OS X) still aren't shipping? So you might still need `$'s/1\xE2\x9C\x81/g`.

Comment: @rici: Actually, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021137/print-unicode-character) it was bash 4.2, not 4.0. (At any rate, Apple's still shipping 3.2.)

Comment: @abarnert: I think it was added sometime between 4.1 and 4.2, so OS X's `bash` won't have it. (But I believe its `zsh` will).

Comment: @rici: You're right about zsh; Apple's shipping 5.0+ since at least 10.9, and I think much longer, and 5.0.0 definitely has Unicode escapes. But I think most OS X users use bash. (Although I know a couple who are still pissed off that Apple switched the default from tcsh, which was good enough for their NeXTcubes…)