# Tradition division symbol in bash

Tags: bash, math, centos, division, symbols

writing a little bash script on CentOS for my kids to practice math and would like to display the tradition division line with two dots rather than the standard "/".

Is there a way to do this in the linux bash shell?

Comment: Wouldn't `echo ÷` work?

Answer (score 3):

You can print Unicode characters with hex values like this:

```
$ printf '\u00F7'
÷
```

or

```
$ echo -e '\u00F7'
÷
```

Comment: Is there something environmental extra? I am still not seeing what I need in CentOS 7 bash.
$ env | grep -i lang
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @morawski What is the output of `bash --version` ? Does @cyrus answer work ? `printf "%b" "\xc3\xb7"`. It migh be because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021137/print-unicode-character#16021300

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
printf "%b" "\xc3\xb7"
```

Output:

```
÷
```